# PHPUnit - testing for exception not thrown?

Tags: php, phpunit

PHP 7.4 and PHPUnit 9

Using the PHPUnit homepage example (https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html):

```
private function ensureIsValidEmail(string $email): void
{
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                '"%s" is not a valid email address',
                $email
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The homepage also shows us how to test the exception is thrown using the `expectException()` method:

```
public function testCannotBeCreatedFromInvalidEmailAddress(): void
{
    $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);

    Email::fromString('invalid');
}
```

That's great. But what if I want to test the exception is ***not*** thrown given valid input ?

Looking at the docs (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#testing-exceptions) there seems to be no mention of an inverse method to `expectException()`  ?

How should I approach this ?

EDIT TO ADD:

Just to make it perfectly clear, I'm looking to test an `Email::fromString('valid.email@example.com');` scenario, i.e. that the exception is ***not*** thrown.

Comment: The `testCanBeCreatedFromValidEmailAddress` method tests the happy path. It won't pass if an exception was thrown. Given that, you don't have to explicitly check for the exception.

Comment: I'd just annotate the test method with `@doesNotPerformAssertions`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If an uncaught or unexpected exception is thrown, the test will fail. You don't have to do anything special, just run the code being tested. If there are no other assertions in the test method, you'll also have to do `$this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();` or you'll get a warning that the test doesn't perform any assertions.

```
public function testCannotBeCreatedFromInvalidEmailAddress(): void
{
    $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
    Email::fromString('invalid'); // If this throws an exception, the test will fail.
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear (or I misunderstand your answer).  To make it explicitly clear, what I want to test is `Email::fromString('validemail@example.com')`  ?  i.e. I was hoping to find an `exceptionNotThrown()` method (doesn't exist as far as I can tell).

Comment: You don't need something like `ExceptionNotThrown()` because that's the default behavior. Just run the code and the test will pass if no exception is thrown.

Comment: This answer works. But if someone also need another approach, maybe he can try this one too. https://guh.me/how-to-assert-that-an-exception-is-not-thrown-on-phpunit or this one http://www.ashleysheridan.co.uk/blog/Testing+Exception+Not+Thrown+With+PHPUnit (I don't prefer the second one tho)